# Redemption CreateItemFromTemplate analogue

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

Is there an Redemption analogue of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application.CreateItemFromTemplate() function to open exported before .oft (task items) or .vcf (appointment items) files ?

It works with Redemption.IRDOFolder2.Import  for me, but it import item into the corresponding folder (calendar or task).
I use C# language.
Thank you in avance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new item first (`RDOFolder.Items.Add`), and then import the OFT file using `RDOMail.Import(..., olMsg)`.

Comment: I used next code:    Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem appointmentItemRDO = null;
appointmentItemRDO = calendarFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Appointment") as Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem;
appointmentItemRDO.Import(filePath, Redemption.rdoSaveAsType.olICal);   and it works in the same way as i mentioned before (using IRDOFolder2.Import). But i DON'T need to import the item into the Calendar folder, i just need to create item from the file and make further processing.  How can i do it without import() function ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to create it in the Calendar folder? You can create a temporary MSG file using RDOSession.CreateMesageFromMsgFile(..., olAppointmentItem)

Comment: Yes, i don't wanna to create any items in calendar/tasks folders.  I tested it:   Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem appointmentItemRDO = Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem) RDOSession.CreateMesageFromMsgFile(..., olAppointmentItem);   but got EMPTY appointment item (with default fields values), i mean it has no fields imported from .ics-file like for example SUBJECT = "imported_subject_value".    Also i tried to use GetMessageFromMsgFile() and cast return object to Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem but got exception.

Comment: _NameSpace.OpenSharedItem() - This method is used to open iCalendar appointment (.ics) files, vCard (.vcf) files, and Outlook message (.msg) files.   And i need to open calendar appointments using RDO too.  But i don't need to IMPORT it to calendar folder !  Is there an RDO analogue ?

Comment: OpenSharedItem in OOM creates a temporary item in the default store.
RDOSession.CreateMesageFromMsgFile creates an empty item, did you import the ICS file using Import?

Comment: Thank you, Dima ! I think i have found the solution and tested it:  Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem appointmentItemRDO = null;  appointmentItemRDO = (Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem) RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile(filePath_tmp, OutlookInterop.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem, 1);
appointmentItemRDO.Import(filePath, Redemption.rdoSaveAsType.olICal);                    After that i got correct appointmentItemRDO, imported from .ics-file.

Comment: Then i need to delete temporary file which was created while CreateMessageFromMsgFile() call. I used: InteropMarshal.ReleaseComObject(ref appointmentItemRDO); if (File.Exists(fileTemp)) File.Delete(fileTemp);

Comment: May be you can propose better solution ? Without making temp-file and delete it ? Also what was interesing: InteropMarshal.ReleaseComObject works fine BUT InteropMarshal.FinalReleaseComObject don't ! Why ? Some strange marshal bug ? it should set reference count to COM-object to 0, but something works wrong.  Also cast appointmentItemRDO to IDisposable and call IDisposable.Dispose leads to exception.    Again, thank you very much for your help. Spasibo !

Comment: You can just call RDOMail.Delete - for a message created on top of an MSG file, it will delete the file.

Comment: yes! it works fine with ((Redemption.RDOAppointmentItem)appointmentItem).Delete(Redemption.redDeleteFlags.dfHardDelete);                                                   InteropMarshal.FinalReleaseComObject(ref appointmentItem);                               now it's totally what i wanted to do. Thank you, Dmitry. Should i make answer to my question and will be it helpful for Redemption usability & helping other RDO users ?

Comment: Sure, I don't see why not.